# Alternative to if-elif clause

Tags: python

I made a script to download from booru imageboards. Is there any alternative to make this ugly if-elif clause looks simpler in case I want to add more booru imageboard choices? Thanks.

```
def runbooru(tags, limit=0, booru="Danbooru"):
    tag = Danbooru(tags, limit)
    if booru == "Danbooru":
        tag = Danbooru(tags, limit)
    elif booru == "Gelbooru":
        tag = Gelbooru(tags, limit)
    elif booru == "Rule34":
        tag = Rule34(tags, limit)
    elif booru == "Konachan":
        tag = Konachan(tags, limit)
    elif booru == "Yandere":
        tag = Yandere(tags, limit)
    elif booru == "Safebooru":
        tag = Safebooru(tags, limit)
    return tag
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a dictionary:

```
processors = {f.__name__: f for f in (
    Danbooru, Gelbooru, Konachan, Yandere, Safebooru)}
if booru in processors:
    tag = processors[booru](tags, limit)
```

Functions are objects too, you can store them in other objects like dictionaries and lists.

If you meant `Danbooru` to be the default, you can use `dict.get()` here too:

```
processors = {f.__name__: f for f in (
    Danbooru, Gelbooru, Konachan, Yandere, Safebooru)}
tag = processors.get(booru, Danbooru)(tags, limit)
```

This'll use the `Danbooru` function if the `booru` value is not a key in the dictionary.

Comment: This works! Thanks a lot. I've thinking about creating dictionary too but doesn't know how to make it to work with my functions. This explains it :)